# what is the limit of $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{a}\cdot \lfloor{\frac{b}{x}\rfloor}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

> find the limit of:
>
> $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{a}\cdot  \lfloor{\frac{b}{x}\rfloor}$
>
> $ a,b>0$

i know that:
$\lfloor\frac{b}{x}\rfloor\le \frac{b}{x} + 1$; and 
$\lfloor\frac{b}{x}\rfloor\ge \frac{b}{x} -1$

but i cant seem to combine those using the squeezing theorem (i belive the limit is $\frac{b}{a}$)

Comment: What is the limit of $\frac{x}{a} \cdot (\frac{b}{x}-1)$? Or replaced with +1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider two cases: $x>0$ and $x<0$.
In each case multiply your inequalities by $\frac{x}{a}$.
Then, say for $x<0$, you get:

$\frac{b}{a} -\frac{x}{a} \geq \frac{x}{a} \lfloor \frac{b}{x} \rfloor \geq \frac{b}{a}+ \frac{x}{a}.$

Now use the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 4):

$$\lfloor{\frac bx\rfloor}=\frac bx-\left\{\frac bx\right\}\implies$$

$$\frac xa\lfloor\frac bx\rfloor=\frac xa\frac bx-\frac xa\left\{\frac bx\right\}\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}\frac ba$$

Since $\;\frac xa\to 0\;$ and $\;\{b/x\}\;$ is bounded...

Comment: what do the curly brackets represent?

Comment: The fractional part of a number.

Comment: @DonAntonio How would the solution change if it was the floor and ceiling function (not just the floor like in this case) ?